# gzipping in Angular Universal

Tags: angular

I'd like to improve the loading speed of my website and read online that gzipping would help reduce the file size. However, if I add:

```
const compression = require('compression')
server.use(compression);
```

inside the `app()` function in the `server.ts` file, the website keeps loading forever without throwing any errors.

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`compression` is a function. You just need to call it:

```js
server.use(compression());
```

Comment: Thanks! I also just found out that Firebase Hosting gzips files automatically